# How to use event receiver with input http in DAS

Tags: wso2, wso2-das

I reviewed the documentation of DAS, specifically the subject of http event receivers but it is very simple, practically only fill the fields in admin interface. I need a documentation or example of  How programatically I send data to event receiver with input adapter http. I want send this data in json format. Is a get or post request to some url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just send a http POST request with XML or JSON format with the payload in the format defined by the inputstream.